# How the tribes' borders were determined?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, shevatim-12-tribes, real-estate, pinchas

IIRC, the Lot (גורל) was used to match the areas with the tribes (B"B 122b):

> אֶלְעָזָר הַכֹּהֵן הָיָה מְלֻבָּשׁ בְּאוּרִים וְתֻמִּים
>   וְאוֹמֵר בְּרוּחַ הַקֹּדֶשׁ אִם שֵׁבֶט פְּלוֹנִי עוֹלֶה
>   **תְּחוּם פְּלוֹנִי** עוֹלֶה עִמּוֹ
>   וְהַשְּׁבָטִים הָיוּ כְתוּבִים בִּשְׁנֵים עָשָׂר פְּתָקִין
>   **וְי"ב גְּבוּלִין** בְּי"ב פְּתָקִין ...
>
> Elazar... and Joshua and all the Jewish people were standing before him, and a lottery receptacle containing the names of the tribes and another lottery receptacle **containing the names of the boundaries** of the twelve different regions of Eretz Yisrael were placed before him.

I don't see the Torah mentioning how Moses or anyone else knew the boundaries or how they were called or defined (GPS coordinates? Landmarks?).

How those areas/boundaries were determined?

Answer (score 1):

Yehoshua chapters 13 - 19 gives a detailed description of the borders and cities of each tribe’s portion in the land, as was allocated to them by Moshe (in Transjordan) or by the lottery conducted by Yehoshua and Elazar (in Eretz Yisrael proper).

Comment: I don't understand the main part "*as was allocated to them by Moshe"*. please provide support for your claim, otherwise, it should go to comment. Yehoshua describes what was already done.

Comment: Moshe allocated only to the 2.5 tribes. Yehoshua and Elazar to the rest of the tribes after Moshe’s death

Comment: What was written on the lots?

Comment: I don’t know. Does it matter?